# failOverReadOnly not working in mysql-connector-java-5.1.6

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, mysql-connector

The below is the url I am using. dbt1 is a non existent database. dbt2 & dbt3 are valid ones. The expectation is to test failover. Since dbt1 is non existant, it fails over to dbt2. Server starts properly. I am able to make calls to the endpoints. But the calls fails with `Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed`.

```
jdbc:mysql://dbt1:9999:3306,dbt2:3306,dbt3:3306/rs01?autoReconnect=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;secondsBeforeRetryMaster=60&amp;queriesBeforeRetryMaster=10&amp;useSSL=false
```

I am able to write to db2 if I connect to it as the primary. So the issue is not in the database.

```
jdbc:mysql://dbt2:3306/rs01?autoReconnect=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;secondsBeforeRetryMaster=60&amp;queriesBeforeRetryMaster=10&amp;useSSL=false
```

I am using spring boot 2.3.9-RELEASE which imports mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 into the project with spring-boot-starter-webflux.
Why isn't the application unable to write to the failover ?

Comment: Why are you using the ancient version of MySQL Connector/J 5.1.6? At minimum use the latest 5.1.x or better yet a 8.0.x.

Comment: :) Thanks for responding. I just used the default which was bundled with spring boot. I'll think about upgrading in the future.

But I think I found the issue. I am using spring @Value to load the url. In the process `&` are being replaced with `&amp;`. MySql driver splits the url on `&`. So all the properties had a `amp;` prefix. When driver tries to merge the url properties with default properties, the url properties have no effect because of the `amp;` prefix.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.3.9 by default does not depend on MySQL Connector/J 5.1.6, but MySQL Connector/J 8.0.23. If you have 5.1.6, then something is pulling in that older version, you should check the dependency tree and exclude that dependency from getting pulled in, or declare an explicit dependency on 8.0.23 in POM or Gradle file. You should use just `&` to separate properties. You would only use `&amp;` in XML config files (which aren't normally used with Spring Boot).